# Porque é que a palavra masculina "avós" usa raiz feminina?

Tags: etimologia

> Quando era criança passei muitos Verões em casa dos meus avós.

- Uma avó mais outra são "as avós".
- Um avô mais outro são "os avôs".
- Mas um avô mais uma avó são "**os** av**ó**s".
  Esta palavra é um substantivo *masculino*, mas usa a raiz feminina "avó" em vez da raiz masculina "avô".

Porquê?

Qual a justificação para o uso sem concordância?

Comment: Não sei se é um caso de falta de concordância, ou se possa mesmo dizer que a raiz é *avó*. Pode ser simplesmente um plural irregular. O Aulete diz que *avô* vem do latim *aviolus*, Suponhamos que em tempos em português foi *avolo/aviolo*, pronunciado *avôlo/aviôlo*. Nalguns substantivos com este padrão, o *ô* do singular passa a *ó* no plural: miolo, jogo, povo. Por outro lado, temos os *avós* paternos.

Comment: O pai da mãe e o do pai são os *avôs*, era o que eu queria dizer.

Comment: Ocorre que algumas palavras trocam mesmo que seja somente na pronúncia o ô pelo ó: um ovo, dois 'óvos'. 

No caso, por semelhança teríamos um avô, dois avós. Mas não é realmente assim que foi feito.

Temos avôs e avós de pai e mãe. Então para diferenciar definiram que seria:

- um avô, dois avôs 
- uma avó, duas avós
- avós para avôs e avós

Comment: Não me parece que tenha acontecido dessa forma, @AndréLyra ... mas podes sempre escrever uma resposta, para confirmarmos com os votos positivos da comunidade.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Encontrei a explicação no [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/avos-e-avoss/19372). No português medieval as palavras eram ***avoo*** e ***avoa***, e o plural masculino era ***avoos***. Não se usavam acentos nesses tempos, mas presumivelmente a pronúncia era ou evoluiu para ***avôo*** e ***avóa***, donde resultaram ***avô*** e ***avó***. Ao contrário do singular, o plural masculino terá mantido a pronúncia aberta do ***o***, ***avóos***. Isto é relativamente comum no português. Pensem em *miolo*, (*miôlo, miólos*), *tijolo* (*tijôlo, tijólos*) ovo (*ôvo, óvos*), etc. Portanto os plurais eram pronunciados distintamente, ***avóos*** e ***avóas***, mas convergiram para ***avós*** com o encurtamento das palavras. Segundo o artigo, a palavra ***avôs*** apareceu mais tarde para designar apenas homens (o avô paterno e o materno), mantendo-se *avós* para casais e antepassados em geral.

Segundo o Ciberdúvidas e outras fontes, a origem de *avô* e *avó* é o latim *avus* e *avia*, por via dos diminutivos, não atestados, mas que se supõe terem existido, *aviolo* e *aviola*, donde terá também surgido o espanhol [*abuelo* e *abuela*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0DKKo2d) (note-se que não havia acentos na escrita medieval):

> *Aviolo* > *avolo* > *avoo* > *avo* > *avô*,
>
> *Aviola* > *avola* > *avoa* > *avo* > *avó*.

Fui em busca das origens, mas só consegui chegar a ***avoo*** e ***avoa***. A forma feminina é rara. Consegui encontrar apenas duas ocorrências, no [Corpus Informatizado do Português Medieval](http://cipm.fcsh.unl.pt/) (registo necessário):

> Onde, a que matou padre ou madre ou ***avoo ou avoa*** ou irmaão ou irmaã ou ainda tio ou tia, irmaãos de padre ou de madre, se homiçidio foy voluntario, deve fazer dez annos de penitençia, en esta maneira: deve estar huum anno aas horas, ante a porta da eigreja, e deve perseverar en oraçom. O segundo… [(*Penitencial de Martim Perez*, séc. XV.)](http://repositorio.ucp.pt/bitstream/10400.14/4969/1/LS_S1_02_MarioMartins.pdf)
>
> Este meny~' en Castela con Rei Don Alffonsso era,
> seu ***avoo***, que do reino de Galiza o fezera
> vi~ir e que o amava a gran maravil[l]a fera.
> E ar era y sa madre, a que muit' ende prazia,
> Ben per está aos reis d'amaren Santa Maria
> E sa ***avoa*** y era, filla del Rei d' Ingraterra,
> moller del Rei Don Alffonsso,
> [(*Cantigas de Santa Maria*, séc. XIII.)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantigas_de_Santa_Maria)

Curiosamente, nos séculos XIV, XV e XVI, o feminino passa a ser grafado também *avoo*:

> E, dhy a dous ãnos, que estes dous iffantes morrerõ, morreo a rainha dona Maria, ***avoo*** del rey. ([Pedro Afonso](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedro_Afonso,_conde_de_Barcelos), [*Crónica Geral de Espanha*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cr%C3%B3nica_Geral_de_Espanha_de_1344), 1344.)

Encontrei uma meia dúzia de *avoo* significando *avó* e umas dezenas significando *avô*. No século XV aparece também ***avo*** quer para *avô* quer para *avó*, e aparece também *avos*. Imagino que as pronúncias fossem já muito próximas das atuais, e como ainda não se fazia uso sistemático de acentos, os escritores usavam a mesma grafia para ambas as palavras.

Comment: Jacinto, podes adicionar a página da fonte do «Penitencial de Martim Perez»? Eu estava curioso sobre se «d**a** padre ou d**e** madre» está assim no original ou se é um erro de transcrição (duvido...), mas tive dificuldade em encontrar a citação no documento original.

Comment: @ANeves Na verdade, no documento que eu linkei está «de padre ou de madre». Eu copiei o texto do Corpus. O penitencial começa na página 73. Faz um find de *avoa*, que encontras logo.