# Por que razão "ô" do singular passa a "ó" no plural em palavras como "ovo", "jogo", "olho"?

Tags: número-gramatical, fonologia

Há uma certa tendência para palavras paroxítonas com **o** tónico fechado (ô) no singular o terem aberto (ó) no plural. Exemplos com um acento gráfico inexistente na nossa ortografia só para indicar o timbre:

> ôlho, ólhos
>   miôlo, miólos
>   ôvo, óvos
>   ôsso, óssos
>   pôço, póços
>   trôco, trócos
>   pôrco, pórcos
>   nôvo, nóvos
>   jôgo, jógos

E podia continuar aqui a acrescentar exemplos pela noite fora. Isto não é regra universal. Há muitos casos em que o **o** é fechado no singular e no plural: *lôbos, bôlos, môços*, etc. Mas a alternância entre **ô** e **ó** é bastante frequente. Onde há um padrão eu espero uma explicação. Mas qual será?

Há uma alternância parecida entre masculino e feminino: *ôvo, óva; pôço, póça; pôrto, pórta; nôvo, nóva*, etc. Aqui, li algures que é influência da vogal final: dá mais jeito à boca pronunciar **ó** se a seguir tiver de pronunciar um **a**; e mais jeito um **ô** se a seguir vem o som [u] (que é como pronunciamos aqueles oo finais).

Mas esta explicação não serve no caso da alternância entre o singular e plural, porque a vogal final é [u] em ambos os casos. Então, qual é a explicação para a esta alternância?

Comment: Acho a questão interessante, mas seria importante esclarecer por que os resultados de uma busca por *metafonia plural* são insatisfatórios. Por exemplo, [esta](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/sobre-a-metafonia-nominal/25017) e também [esta outra](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/prosodia-coros-corvos-fornos/5034) pergunta do Ciberdúvidas, ou [esta dissertação](http://www.bibliotecadigital.ufmg.br/dspace/bitstream/handle/1843/LHAM-6N6H8U/katia_silva_dissert.pdf?sequence=1).

Comment: Há também as fontes mencionadas [neste artigo](https://www.migalhas.com.br/Gramatigalhas/10,MI126739,11049-Miolo+o+Miolos+o) e também [neste](https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/452).

Comment: @stafusa, eu nem sei se essa busca é insatisfatória, quanto mais... Eu faço essas buscas e leio essas coisas todas mas é para preparar respostas.

Comment: Sim, eu mesmo escreveria uma resposta, se tivesse tempo no momento para ler em detalhe. :-/

Comment: Há [uma pergunta relevante sobre avô-avós](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1887/porque-%c3%a9-que-a-palavra-masculina-av%c3%b3s-usa-raiz-feminina), em que uma autoridade (s'excelência) indica a evolução avoo/avóos -> avô/avó e avoa/avóas -> avó/avós. Estaremos quiçá perante uma situação semelhante?

Comment: @ANeves, creio, tal como disse lá, que essa tendência do "ô" do singular passar a "ó" no plural contribuiu para o plural de *avô* ser *avós* (antigamente teria sido *avôlo, avólos*). Aqui a minha pergunta é porque é que há essa tendência. Vi alguns dos links do stafusa, e vêm lá ideias interessantes.

Comment: Muitas das palavras que indicas com alternância ô/ó têm ditongos nas línguas irmãs (*ue* em asturiano/castelhano/aragonês, *uo* em mirandês), cousa que indica haverem tido em latim um O curto. Seria esta evolução desde o latim o que favorecesse a alternância frente a outros O doutra origem que mantêm a qualidade?

Comment: @guifa, perguntas bem; não sabes a quem... Umas coisas que li entretanto (links indicados pelo stafusa) é que a vogal final no latim era no plural diferente da do singular (embora no português atual sejam iguais), e que isso influenciou o timbre do **o** anterior.

Answer (score 3):

O fenômeno se chama "Plural metafônico". Ocorre com várias palavras que mudam a pronúncia devido à mudança na fala. "Ovos", por exemplo, é estendido o primeiro 'o', o que o torna tônico.

Comment: Wellington Siqueira, bem-vindo ao Portuguese StackExchange! O Jacinto pergunta do motivo desse fenômeno, o que eu, na minha interpretação, não vi. Mas obrigado ainda assim.